# Mutexes available from all the threads

Tags: pthreads, mutex

My question is this i have this piece of code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<pthread.h>
    int number;
   pthread_mutex_t mutex[number];
   pthread_t threads[number];


void *dosomething(void *num)
{
   int *i=num;
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex[i]);
    //dosomething
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex[i]);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) //<-- main
{

    printf("How many threads do you want?");
     scanf("%d",&number);

     int rc,t;
   for(t=1;t<number;t++){
     pthread_mutex_init(&mutex[t],NULL);
     printf("In main: creating thread %d \n", t);
     rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, philospher,(void *)t);
            }

     if (rc){
       printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n",rc);

      exit(0);
            }


   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

When i try to compile it, it says:
      variably modified ‘mutex’ at file scope/
      variably modified ‘threads’ at file scope.
All i want it to create a number of mutexes and threads that the user will have defined and be available from all the threads created.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial answer. Note that there are other errors in your posted code (such as using a pointer as an index) and the following code has only the minimal possible error handling.  I'll let you sort out those details.

```
// ...

int number;
pthread_mutex_t* mutex;  // declare as pointers instead of arrays
pthread_t* threads;      //    so they can be dynamically sized

void alloc_thread_info(int number)
{
    int i;

    // allocate the arrays with the requested size

    mutex = calloc( number, sizeof(*mutex));
    threads = calloc(number, sizeof(*threads));

    if (!mutex || !threads) {
        abort();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
        pthread_mutex_init( &mutex[i]);
    }

    return;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have also placed a printf in the threads saying "Hello Im the number %d thread" but it seems that sometimes when I create for example 5 threads the printf inside the threads sometimes prints less than 5 or sometimes no hellos.